# app crashing at run time after tying to change vision code

Tags: flutter

i worked on an update in my app that is on play store on i want to change the version code which i did in the yaml file but now if i install the apk it will crash at run time. Even the debug mode too is crashing in the emulator. hare are the changes i made:
So after i ran flutter run --verbose this is the error message i got:

```
    C:\Java\just_cook>flutter run -d emulator-5554 --verbose
[  +25 ms] executing: [C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +89 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] b041144f833e05cf463b8887fa12efdec9493488
[   +1 ms] executing: [C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter/] git tag --contains HEAD
[ +269 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --contains HEAD
[   +2 ms] 1.17.3
[  +11 ms] executing: [C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +66 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +57 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +1 ms] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +127 ms] executing: [C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +61 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +52 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +8 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +23 ms] executing: C:\Users\Dell Latitude\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +54 ms] List of devices attached
           0392033956009424       device product:H8025 model:TECNO_KB7 device:TECNO-KB7 transport_id:9
           emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86 model:Android_SDK_built_for_x86 device:generic_x86 transport_id:2
[   +7 ms] C:\Users\Dell Latitude\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell getprop
[  +70 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +7 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +7 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +101 ms] Found plugin firebase_admob at C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_admob-0.9.3+2\
[  +10 ms] Found plugin firebase_core at C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.4.5\
[   +6 ms] Found plugin firebase_core_web at C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core_web-0.1.1+2\
[  +47 ms] Found plugin url_launcher at C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-5.4.11\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_macos at C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_macos-0.0.1+7\
[   +5 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_web at C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_web-0.1.1+6\
[   +5 ms] Found plugin webview_flutter at C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\webview_flutter-0.3.22+1\
[  +62 ms] Found plugin firebase_admob at C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_admob-0.9.3+2\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin firebase_core at C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.4.5\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin firebase_core_web at C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core_web-0.1.1+2\
[  +44 ms] Found plugin url_launcher at C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-5.4.11\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_macos at C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_macos-0.0.1+7\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_web at C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_web-0.1.1+6\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin webview_flutter at C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\webview_flutter-0.3.22+1\
[  +64 ms] Generating C:\Java\just_cook\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +41 ms] ro.hardware = ranchu
[  +29 ms] Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
[  +42 ms] Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
[  +15 ms] C:\Users\Dell Latitude\Downloads\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe C:\Users\Dell
Latitude\Downloads\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root C:\Users\Dell
Latitude\Downloads\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names -Ddart.developer.causal_async_stacks=true
--output-dill C:\Users\DELLLA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tool.c3d83847-b7e6-11ea-8271-e4a7a0d0fff6\app.dill --packages C:\Java\just_cook\.packages -Ddart.vm.profile=false
-Ddart.vm.product=false --bytecode-options=source-positions,local-var-info,debugger-stops,instance-field-initializers,keep-unreachable-code,avoid-closure-call-instructions
--enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root
[  +20 ms] executing: C:\Users\Dell Latitude\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt dump xmltree C:\Java\just_cook\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[  +42 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\Dell Latitude\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt dump xmltree C:\Java\just_cook\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[   +1 ms] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x2
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="2.0.0" (Raw: "2.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="10" (Raw: "10")
               A: package="cook.recipe.justcook" (Raw: "cook.recipe.justcook")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1d
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0xa
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x10
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               E: uses-permission (line=14)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: uses-permission (line=15)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")
               E: uses-permission (line=16)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" (Raw: "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK")
               E: uses-permission (line=17)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" (Raw:
                 "com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE")
               E: uses-permission (line=18)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" (Raw: "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE")
               E: application (line=26)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="justcook" (Raw: "justcook")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" (Raw: "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication")
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: meta-data (line=34)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.ads.ca-app-pub-8204002520550586~7264667450" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.gms.ads.ca-app-pub-8204002520550586~7264667450")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)="ca-app-pub-8204002520550586~7264667450" (Raw: "ca-app-pub-8204002520550586~7264667450")
                 E: activity (line=38)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="cook.recipe.justcook.MainActivity" (Raw: "cook.recipe.justcook.MainActivity")
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=45)
                     E: action (line=46)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=48)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=55)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
                 E: activity (line=59)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x1030007
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.WebViewActivity" (Raw: "io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.WebViewActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: service (line=64)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   E: meta-data (line=67)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=70)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=73)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar" (Raw:
                     "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                 E: activity (line=77)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x103000f
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0xfb0
                 E: provider (line=83)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:authorities(0x01010018)="cook.recipe.justcook.mobileadsinitprovider" (Raw: "cook.recipe.justcook.mobileadsinitprovider")
                   A: android:initOrder(0x0101001a)=(type 0x10)0x64
                 E: receiver (line=89)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver")
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: receiver (line=94)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver" (Raw:
                   "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" (Raw: "android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES")
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=99)
                     E: action (line=100)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" (Raw: "com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER")
                 E: service (line=104)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService")
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: service (line=108)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" (Raw: "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: receiver (line=114)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" (Raw: "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=118)
                     E: action (line=119)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" (Raw: "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")
                 E: provider (line=123)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:authorities(0x01010018)="cook.recipe.justcook.firebaseinitprovider" (Raw: "cook.recipe.justcook.firebaseinitprovider")
                   A: android:initOrder(0x0101001a)=(type 0x10)0x64
                 E: activity (line=129)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x1030010
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: meta-data (line=134)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.version" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.version")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=@0x7f060000
[  +21 ms] executing: C:\Users\Dell Latitude\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +83 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\Dell Latitude\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[        ] --------- beginning of main
           06-26 20:53:55.730 I/GnssLocationProvider( 1807): WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0,
           com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@4fb3726)
[  +31 ms] <- compile package:justcook/main.dart
[  +23 ms] executing: C:\Users\Dell Latitude\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[  +54 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
           Version 4986621
           Installed as C:\Users\Dell Latitude\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
[   +5 ms] executing: C:\Users\Dell Latitude\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[  +61 ms] Building APK
[  +53 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[   +3 ms] gradle.properties already sets `android.enableR8`
[   +7 ms] Using gradle from C:\Java\just_cook\android\gradlew.bat.
[   +2 ms] C:\Java\just_cook\android\gradlew.bat mode: 33279 rwxrwxrwx.
[  +23 ms] executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[ +173 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "1.8.0_212-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
[   +5 ms] executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[ +157 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "1.8.0_212-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
[   +5 ms] executing: [C:\Java\just_cook\android/] C:\Java\just_cook\android\gradlew.bat -Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-x86 -Ptarget=C:\Java\just_cook\lib\main.dart
-Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
[+3544 ms] > Configure project :app
[   +3 ms] google-services plugin could not detect any version for com.google.android.gms or com.google.firebase, default version: 9.0.0 will be used.
```

Comment: You have to set the pubspec to `version: 2.0.0+2`, that way the `local.properties` wont change back

Comment: it that the cos of the crashing too

Comment: The crash could've been caused by anything. run with 'flutter run --verbose` maybe you'll get error message

Comment: ok i did what you said and the  local.properties is not changing back thanks but its still crashing

Comment: i got an error message

Comment: Post the error message in the Question

Comment: ok i just posted it check it out

Comment: Seems you posted the wrong error. There should be an error message just before the one you posted

Comment: ok i will send the whole message

Comment: so i just editted it and add the full error message

Comment: pls are still here

Comment: do `flutter run -d emulator-5554 --verbose` then post the log. The current log you posted said you didn't specify a device.

Comment: ok i will right now

Comment: so i just post some of i couldnt post all bcos it wont let me its only take 30000 words

Comment: You can paste on paste bin then add the link here

Comment: where can i find the paste bin